# schedule a EC2 to start and Stop by auto Scaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, aws-auto-scaling

I want to schedule an Ec2 for start and stop by auto scaling, is it possible? If it is how can I?

I want to schedule an Ec2 for start and stop by auto scaling without lamda function.

Comment: First search result for "AWS Scheduled Auto Scaling": https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/ec2-auto-scaling-scheduled-scaling.html

Comment: To auto start-stop ec2 servers, you can use the AWS Instance scheduler too. For Auto scaling requirement, check the official docs to get better idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use scheduled actions to do this

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/ec2-auto-scaling-scheduled-scaling.html

A example of what this looks like is this (This will make the ASG have 0 instances in it overnight )
[image: example]